# Joining 2 table with different record number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to join 2 table to become 1 table
My Table :

1. tbl_Item
2. tbl_conversion

tbl_Item Fields is :

1. Item_Code
2. Item_Name

tbl_conversion Fields is :

1. Conversion_Id
2. Item_Code1
3. Qty1
4. Item_Code2
5. Qty2

-. tbl_Item Record :

| Item_Code | Item_Name |
| --- | --- |
| C0001 | Pencil |
| C0002 | Pen |
| C0003 | Ink |
| C0004 | Brushes |

-. tbl_Conversion Record :

| Conversion_Id | Item_Code1 | Qty1 | Item_Code2 | Qty2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X0001 | C0001 | 10 | C0002 | 30 |
| X0002 | C0003 | 20 | C0004 | 40 |

So, what I want to do is I want to take Item_Name from tbl_Item and merge that to tbl_conversion

The result I want is like this:

| Conversion_Id | Item_Code1 | Item_Name1 | Qty1 | Item_Code2 | Item_Name2 | Qty2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X0001 | C0001 | Pencil | 10 | C0002 | Pen | 30 |
| X0002 | C0003 | Ink | 20 | C0004 | Brushes | 40 |

What I've tried is :

```sql
Select *, 
(select Item_Name From tbl_Item JOIN tbl_Conversion ON tbl_Conversion.Item_Code1 = tbl_Item.Item_Code) as Item_Name1,
(select Item_Name From tbl_Item JOIN tbl_Conversion ON tbl_Conversion.Item_Code2 = tbl_Item.Item_Code) as Item_Name2 
FROM tbl_Conversion
```

The result is right if there's only 1 record on tbl_Conversion.
But if there's more than 1 record, then sql will return error message:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data, desired results and your attempt.

Comment: Note that tables have _rows_ and _columns_, not records or fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your subqueries don't refer to the tbl_Conversion row in your main query, but to all rows in the table.

Here is the corrected query:

```
select
  c.*, 
  (select i.item_name from tbl_item i where i.item_code = c.item_code1) as item_name1,
  (select i.item_name from tbl_item i where i.item_code = c.item_code2) as item_name2 
from tbl_conversion c;
```

More typical would be joins:

```
select
  c.*, 
  i1.item_name as item_name1,
  i2.item_name as item_name2 
from tbl_conversion c
join tbl_item i1 on i1.item_code = c.item_code1
join tbl_item i2 on i2.item_code = c.item_code2;
```